# Difference between two arrays and create a special array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I think it will be better to give an example to describe my problem clearly.

Input:

`a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`

`b=[2 5 8]`

Output:

`c=[1 0 2 3 0 4 5 0 6 7]`

I am trying to solve this problem using MATLAB, and looking for any efficient way or MATLAB in build function to solve this problem.

I also tried to solve it, but it requires one `for` loop and few `if-else` statements inside it.

Comment: They are merging two arrays in a special manner, but this is not the case here.

Comment: then you should "clearly" explain how your example is supposed to work

Comment: I have no clue how your output is supposed to follow logically from your input. It would be worth to share you code snippet that you don't seem to like.

Comment: Sorry, I realize there is some problem with my given desired output. Please check the edited version.

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard to point out about the mistake.

Comment: @m.s. hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: no, not clear at all; where does the `6` come from? just post the code you already have, don't let people guess how it *could* work

Comment: yes yes. you are right. another silly mistake was there. Input was wrong. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I do not know which will work better, but I got an idea and thought to share it.

```
a = 1:10;
b = [2 5 8];
c = ones(1,10);
c(b) = zeros(size(b));
c(c~=0) = 1:(length(a)-length(b));
```

Comment: That's pretty nice. I have one suggestion, however. If you use the final `1:(length(a)-length(b))` as an index into your original array `a` you can make your solution more general. `c(c~=0) = a(1:(length(a)-length(b)));` This way, `a` is not restricted to only sequences from `1:n`.

Comment: Hi @beaker!! Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I did it because my desired output was in that format, and yes of course you can do that to get a more general version of the solution.